setting the backend name in using GKE
When setting up an ingress and a service using kubernetes manifest is it possible to have a fixed name for the backend?  Once I apply the manifest kubernetes generates a backend that looks like this:
kubectl describe ingress my-ingress | grep ingress.kubernetes.io/backends


ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: '{"k8s1-27fde173-default-my-service-80-8d4ca500":"HEALTHY","k8s1-27fde173-kube-system-default-http-backend-80-18dfe76c":"HEALTHY"}

Is it possible to pre-determine the name of the service to something like
k8s1-27fde173-default-my-service-80-v4 rather than the random bit at the end?
The reason for this is that I need to apply TF code related to this name, thus it would be useful if the name was predefined rather than randomly generated by k8s.
Sample ingress manifest
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 80

